# Querying values from one side of a many-to-many relationship?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, inner-join

I have three different MySQL tables:

doctors:

```
| id | name  |
+----+-------+
| 1  | john  |
| 2  | maria |
| 3  | ann   |
```

clinics:

```
| id | location |
+----+----------+
| 1  | New York |
| 2  | Chicago  |
| 3  | LA       |
```

doctor_clinic:

```
| doctor_id | clinic_id |
+-----------+-----------+
|     1     |     2     |
|     1     |     3     |
|     2     |     1     |
|     3     |     1     |
|     3     |     3     |
```

Table doctor_clinic is a relational table.

How can I query all doctors for LA (id=3)?

Comment: This question is very, very basic. You really should read a tutorial for sql first.

Comment: Since this has been answered already, I would like to just drop a quick [resource](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) that might help a little bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've learned by now, you need an inner join to do this, but if you were that confused on this problem I think it's important to take the time to understand what's happening here.

The intersection table doesn't just relate clinics to doctors, but it's creating a [many to many](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_%28data_model%29) relationship. In other words, one doctor can belong to *many* clinics, and one clinic can have *many* doctors. This would make sense in a real world application, and it is important to think about these real world models to help understand your problem.

So, before I explain writing the query, let's think about what has to be done here:

> How can I query all doctors for LA (id=3)?

It's obvious that just the clinic table is not enough, and we know that clinics are connected to doctors through the doctor_clinic table, so we need to join that. A brief syntax explanation of a join is:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
JOIN table2 ON table1.relatedColumn = table2.relatedColumn
```

Start by getting all the doctor ids from the doctor_clinic table by joining it with the clinic table, like this:

```
SELECT dc.doctor_id
FROM doctor_clinic dc
JOIN clinic c ON c.id = dc.clinic_id
```

If all you needed were the doctor's ids, then this is enough. To get the doctor's name, however, we need to join in the doctors table. The doctors table is connected to doctor_clinic using the doctor_id and id columns:

```
SELECT d.name
FROM doctor d
JOIN doctor_clinic dc ON d.id = dc.doctor_id
JOIN clinic c ON c.id = dc.clinic_id
WHERE c.id = 3;
```

You can just add the condition for clinic id 3 in the where clause. If you didn't know it was id 3, just change the line to `WHERE c.location = 'LA'`. I hope this helped explain the problem to you.

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b87af/2) example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use inner join for this:

```
select d.* from 
Doctors d inner join doctor_clinic dc = on d.DOctorId = dc.DoctorId
inner join Clinics c on c.ClinicId = dc.ClinicID
where c.ClinicId = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Use simple **JOIN** to fetch the result:

Try this:

```
SELECT D.id, D.name
FROM Doctors D 
INNER JOIN doctor_clinic DC ON D.id = DC.doctorId 
INNER JOIN Clinics C ON C.id = DC.clinicId 
WHERE C.name = 'LA';
```